# iPad app - CALayer makes it very laggy when rotating

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, core-animation, calayer

Im currently working on an universal app, and in one of my view controllers i have the following xib:

```
View
 -ImageView
 -TableView
 -ImageView
 -View (called tblviewContainer in the following snippet of code)
```

In my viewdidload method i have made an layer which i will put on my view(tblviewcontainer) so that some of the top and the bottom of the screen is gradient.

```
[tblViewContainer addSubview:self.tableView];
[tblViewContainer sendSubviewToBack:self.tableView];

if (!maskLayer)
{
    maskLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];

    UIColor* outerColorSetup = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.0];
    UIColor* innerColorSetup = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0];

    CGColorRef outerColor = outerColorSetup.CGColor;
    CGColorRef innerColor = innerColorSetup.CGColor;

    maskLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         (__bridge id )outerColor,
                         (__bridge id)innerColor,
                         (__bridge id)innerColor, 
                         (__bridge id)outerColor, nil];

    maskLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.01],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.04],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];

    maskLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                  self.tableView.frame.size.width,
                                  self.tableView.frame.size.height);

    maskLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;

    tblViewContainer.layer.mask = maskLayer;

}
```

In my app it is possible to rotate, and when i do that with the layer on, it is very slow/laggy when i rotate (only on ipad 3!).

When i rotate i do the following: (from portrait->landscape)

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {

    }
    else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        _landscape = [[ipad_VideoListViewController_Landscape alloc] initWithNibName:@"ipad_VideoListViewController_Landscape" bundle:nil];
        _landscape.scroolViewContentOffset = scroolViewContentOffset;
         [self.view.layer setRasterizationScale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale];
          self.view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;


        NSMutableArray *viewCons = [[[self navigationController]viewControllers] mutableCopy];
        [viewCons removeLastObject];
        [viewCons addObject:_landscape];
        [[self navigationController]setViewControllers:viewCons animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Worst part is it works flawlessly on the ipad 2 with the layer active, but ipad 3 cant seem to handle it. It even seems that the things i do with animation on ipad 2 (which works), cant be handle on the ipad 3. E.g. i made my own tableview header cells / tableview cells, and they also lag if i use them on ipad 3.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Added the following two lines: (to willrotate)
         [self.view.layer setRasterizationScale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale];
          self.view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;

And the following line to shouldautorotate:
self.view.layer.shouldRasterize = NO;

It helped very little, so its still not smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some transparent images instead and its running smooth.

Still, if anyone know why this does not work, i would like to know.

Had to find this solution, because i have a deadline :).

And thanks for the comment Michael!

Answer (score 0):

Try [rasterizing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/shouldRasterize) in your willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:

```
self.view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

And then in your didRotateToInterfaceOrientation:

```
self.view.layer.shouldRasterize = NO;
```

Also, make sure your layers are opaque where possible.

Comment: I will try it later, and will post if it helps or not!

Comment: It didnt work. Still the unsmooth rotation as before. And instead of self.view.layer, isnt it supposed to be tblviewcontainer.layer? Because its there the layer is added to. Never the less, i tried both, and none of them made a difference. (and i also guess, that i have to to this in my landscape view controller also? which i did also! :))